# search filter using regex similar to sql Like 'a%'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

i have this search filter, how do i implement a regex to make it work like the sql ( Like 'a%' ) that finds any values that starts with *a* ?

```
function SFName() {

    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
    input = document.getElementById("SFNameInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        if (td) {
            if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                tr[i].style.display = "";

            } else {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is what i tried :

```
function SFName() {

    var input, regex, table, tr, td, i;
    input = document.getElementById("SFNameInput").value;
    regex = /^/gi;
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
        if (td) {
            if (regex.exec(td.innerHTML).indexOf(input) > -1) {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j7t5d9ud/

Comment: Does `/^a.*/` do what you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check starts with you can use `myStr.indexOf(value) === 0`.  The regex doesn't appear to be necessary here.

This line

`if (regex.exec(td.innerHTML).indexOf(input) > -1) {`

becomes

`if (td.innerHTML.indexOf(input) === 0) {`

Comment: for a search like dfg it results asdfghj , i want results that start with dfg

Comment: `'asdfghj'.indexOf('dfg')` returns 2.  It's not going to pass the if statement up there unless it starts with 'dfg' (note the === 0)

Comment: omg you are right , the problem is something else now , as i type d in search box , it hides the columns that don't match and when i type f it wont look in the hidden rows so it shows nothing :(

Comment: indexOf is case sensetive (so you should upperCase the innerHTML), you were also using `indexOf(input)` where you wanted `indexOf(filter)`.  Here's a fixed version: https://jsfiddle.net/j7t5d9ud/1/

Comment: what if my names in my database is stored Nvarchar ? it still works ?

Comment: That should be fine, as long as `td.innerHTML` is a string without markup it should work.

Comment: it doesnt make any sense , it works in the fiddel , it works with indexOf(input) > -1 , but it doesn't work with indexOf(input) ===0 , Your answer is correct tho , thank you sir

Comment: make sure `input` is a string, `input = document.getElementById("SFNameInput");` returns the html element.  I changed your fiddle to use your `filter` variable

Answer (score 1):

To find any values that start with `a` use: `/^a[\s\S]*/` or `/^a.*/`

`^` gets makes sure the match starts at the beginning.

`a` matches a.

`[\s\S]` or `.` matches all.

`*` matches 0 or more of the preceding character. In this case it's a wildcard.

**EDIT:**

To implement this you would replace filter with:

```
filter = new RegExp("^" + input.value + ".*", "i");
```

and the condition to:

```
if (td.innerHTML.match(filter)) {
  tr[i].style.display = "";
} else {
  tr[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

The "i" in the RegExp makes the regular expression case insensitive.

Comment: i know , i used regex before , idk how to implement it in the search filter , im confused

Comment: You use String.match(<regex>)

What are you trying to match?

Comment: i want my search filter to find all values starting with the input text , dont know if regex is even the right aproach

Comment: thank you , your code also works fine ,but it doesn't work for me in visual studio 2017 asp.net mvc 5 , your code works in fiddle but not in my project i don't know why !! when i type something all row disappear , its the same with the above answer , strange ...